# Thinkpad T440 fan not working after replacement

Tags: laptop, fan, thinkpad

So i have a Thinkpad T440 laptop and it was giving me fan error on startup, i decided to change the fan and it didn't work at all.
It was the exact same fan except there was one difference, the original fan had 5 wires connected to the connector and the new one i bought had 4 wires
Is it only supposed to work when there are 5 wires connected?
Yes I have tried the fan and it completely works, it only does not work when i connect it to the laptop or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sounds like you purchased an incompatible part if the replacement fan only had 4 cables instead of 5.

Answer (score 0):

> the original fan had 5 wires connected to the connector and the new
> one i bought had 4 wires

You need to use the OEM Fan replacement in order that the connections and also the signals to / from the Fan work properly.

You can ask Lenovo if they still stock the Fan.

Otherwise there are places where you can get them

[T440 Fan](https://www.amazon.ca/Laptop-Replacement-Cooling-ThinkPad-Original/dp/B08JPFM393)

This one from an Amazon source clearly has the 5 wires needed. It says currently unavailable, but this is the kind of search you need to do.

There are also Fans on eBay - check the supplier source for good fan or return if DOA.

[Ebay source](https://www.ebay.ca/sch/i.html?_nkw=lenovo%20t440s%20fan)

Comment: Is there no other alternate?

Comment: You need to search the various sources and look for one. Both links above showed the 5 wires you need and eBay had sources with fans. So you need to look for a source you can work with.

Comment: I got an X230 Keyboard from "nordic keyboard" via eBay. It was a new product and fit my X230 perfectly. eBay may be a viable source of Fans for you.

Comment: Can't seem to find one with five wires, can't i somehow just use a four wired one?

Comment: You need a five wire Fan for all the connections to work well .   This one claims to be in stock. ... https://www.ebay.ca/itm/324363318700?hash=item4b858f75ac:g:hHgAAOSweKRhrsg4     ... If Lenovo does not stock the fan (out of stock) eBay is the next best choice.